# How to implement 'invite to download' feature in a Cordova/PhoneGap application on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, download, invite

I would like to include a menu item in my Android app (built using Cordova/PhoneGap) that provides users with the ability to invite their friends to download the app from Google Play.

Does anyone know of an existing solution for this?  I have not had much luck finding one.

On BlackBerry10, this is extremely easy to do (literally 1 line of code). It leverages the OS and BBM to share the download URL of your app with your closest friends:

```
blackberry.bbm.platform.users.inviteToDownload();
```

[link](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/beta/blackberry.bbm.platform.users.html#jbo1385148784097)

Please tell me something similar like this exists for Android (iOS?) ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use this plugin and works perfectly: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

It's a sharing plugin that allows a lot of configuration options. You could configure it so users share a link to your app on Google Play. The documentation explains how to set everything up.